# Android: No Activity found to handle Intent error?

Tags: android, android-intent

Im getting the error in the title when just messing around with android programming:

Code :

```
package co.uk.mypchealth.whatami;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                       sleep(3000);
                       Intent menuIntent = new Intent("co.uk.mypchealth.whatami.JAVAMENU");
                       startActivity(menuIntent);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

and the manifest :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="co.uk.mypchealth.whatami"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.whatami.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".JavaMenu"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.whatami.JAVAMENU" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>

</manifest>
```

Im Hoping its something simple i mean jeeze the app does nothing yet lol.... i have the intent declared and and all the names i have checked and double checked ... just cant see the wood from the trees. Any help would be great.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your error. If you cannot interpret what the stack trace is telling you, edit your question and paste in that stack trace (formatted as source).

Comment: Change this `android:name=".JavaMenu"` to `android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.whatami.JAVAMENU"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
     Intent menuIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, JavaMenu.class);
     startActivity(menuIntent);
        }
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, This has worked. I followed a tutorial and originally it worked like i had done it..... however when i went back to the start and was just going through on my own just to get to grips ... second time it didnt work ? Could you provide a quick explination as to why your method works better against the other.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
        <activity
            android:name=".JavaMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.whatami.JAVAMENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

you have defined the app name in both activities try to change this activity declaration to :

```
 <activity   android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.whatami.JavaMenu" >    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, i originally had that and as part of my quest to find the answer i changed it to .JavaMenu so that doesnt work.